# Section of plane for bombs, and section for troops

Tags: vocabulary, military

What do you call that part of a plane (specifically a bomber) where the bombs are held, loaded and dispatched?

Also, in a military aircraft, what do you call the part where the soldiers are seated before parachuting out of the plane?

Comment: The first is the bomb bay.

Comment: Bomb bay & Fuselage

Comment: Seems to me that this information could be easily searchable....voting to close.

Comment: http://aviation.stackexchange.com

Comment: Yeah, any further questions should be in the Aviation SE group.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I didn't know there was an aviation SE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of those areas are bays or sections of an airplane.

The **Bomb Bay** in a **bomber** holds the bombs before deployment. You can see this term on the [B-2's Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northrop_Grumman_B-2_Spirit#Armaments_and_equipment).

The **Cargo Bay** in a **freight transport aircraft** holds the troops before they're deployed. Like in the [C-130](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_C-130_Hercules) for a run out the back of the plane style jump you see in the movies/video games.

The **Passenger Bay** in a **troop transport aircraft** would be an appropriate name if the aircraft is designed more for carrying people than general cargo. An example of this would be the [C-47](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_C-47_Skytrain) aircraft used during WW2 to transport the 101<sup>st</sup> Airborne Division to their drops.

---

All of these "bays" are within the fuselage of the aircraft, because the [fuselage](https://www.google.com/search?q=fuselage&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) is simply: the main body of an aircraft.

Comment: +1. Yes, "cargo bay" comes to mind, but is it the only or even the most widespread term? I'm not sure.

Comment: I don't think paratroop aircraft have passenger bays. Paratroops don't think of themselves as passengers.

Comment: @DJClayworth I agree they don't view themselves as passengers like people riding in a commercial jet. "Troop Bay" doesn't ring true to me. Regardless, of their attitude their role *is to be passengers* until they reach their drop zone. If you find a good reference please edit it in.